# How do I define this differential equation to solve with Runge-Kutta method?

Tags: python, ode, runge-kutta

I am making a dynamic a dynamic model of a solar collector to find its oultet Temperature. The equation I am usin is the following:

[Collector equation for the dynamic model:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYLdM.png)

For  this equation, Tm is defined by the following equation

Tm = (TFin + TFout)/2

At the end, I need to plot TFout as a function of time. TFin is a known constant. I have to do the solution using the Runge-Kutta method.

I have been trying to follow some youtube tutorials for Runge-Kutta in Python, but I can't figure out how to properly define the function given that time is not an explicit variable in the equation.

Comment: In a general way. Ordinary diferential equation could be expressed as: dX/dt = f(X,t). first of all you need to define wich values are constants and wich not. Then create a function that represents "f" that takes as input the actual state X, and the variable t, then just use it to apply runge-kutta as the tutorial (if there's no explicit dependence of t in f then just do nothing with t in the function)

Comment: Can you use `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`? Check out the documentation and the examples there.